# A javascript inside my Wordpress page content stops other scripts on the page from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I set up a questionnaire on my Wordpress-based website that includes a script. That script is based in the content () section of the page. However, now other scripts on the page stopped working (e.g. drop-down menus, dynamic display of page titles, etc.). Does my script somehow make all other scripts on the page stop working, and if so, is there an easy edit to my script that could fix this?

The page where the problem occurs is here: http://paracelsus-suchttherapie.ch/selbsttests/alkoholsucht-selbsttest/

and the script I'm talking about reads as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){ 
function calcscore(){
 var score = 0;
 $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
     score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
 });
 $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
} 
$().ready(function(){
 $(".calc").change(function(){
     calcscore()
 });
});
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Please avoid linking to an external site. Also, did you check the console log for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is likely due to you referencing the `$` variable directly (which in WordPress is not mapped to jQuery as you are expecting due to jQuery being in `noConflict()` mode).

Start your script with `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` to assign jQuery to $

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I solved it with replacing all the $ with jQuery. Working smoothly now.